# NavigationController.PushViewController moves the navigation bar as well

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios10

See the attached GIF image to see the problem. Notice that upon tapping the Next button, new controller is pushed and it seems like it pushes new navigation bar on top of the existing one. Normally we know only everything under navigation bar moves and navigation bar doesn't. I am using NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true) to push controller.

[image]

Comment: What is `controller` that you are pushing and how did you create the instance?

Comment: I think the issue is that your previous view's title *conversation options* is too wide, so the *Add People* title ends up offset.  When you push the next view, the layout of the navigation bar is animated back.  Perhaps try changing the "conversation options" title and see if that fixes the issue

Comment: No it makes no difference. Problem is still there

Comment: For some reason the leading edge shadow of the pushed view controller is appearing  on top of the navigation bar, rather than under it.  Can you provide more code?   How did you set up your navigation controller?

Comment: interestingly when i push the first controller (the one that shows Next button), i don't see this problem. It only happens when i push the second controller. So i guess it has nothing to do with the navigation controller.

Comment: Then can you show any code for the initialiser for the second view controller?  How are you setting its frame?

Comment: I tried pushing the instance of UIViewController and problem is still there. That means it is not my controller; it has to be something else.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150891/discussion-between-paulw11-and-asad).

Comment: how do you set you navigationbar (green color)

Answer (score 0):

Is your next view controller is embedded in its own Navigation Controller, if so you should try having one Navigation controller and push the View controller in that.

**UPDATE**

```
 let transition:CATransition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.7
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    self.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
```

Transition types:

```
 kCATransitionFromLeft
 kCATransitionFromBottom
 kCATransitionFromRight
 kCATransitionFromTop
```

Comment: no the next controller is just a UIViewController and NOT UINavigationViewController

Comment: @Paulw11 controller is the instance of the class that inherits UIViewController. I am creating it the by just calling its empty constructor and pushing it using NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, true)

Comment: I think you are updating the Nav bar content right but you dont want to see that move motion in Nav bar. Just try making the animation false.NavigationController.PushViewController(controller, false)

Comment: but false removes the animation for controllers's view as well. I just want the animation for controller's view and not for the nav bar. Just like it normally happens when you  push controller on nav controller stack.

Comment: just to check whether my controller has a problem, i tried pushing the UIViewController without any luck.

Comment: Check my updated comment, it may help you to provide animation to your view.

Comment: ok i will try this solution but what might be causing this issue in the first place. I have a tile and right button in the first nav bar. Then in the second controller's viewDidLoad, i set the new right button and title.

Comment: Thats what I already pointed in starting " 
I think you are updating the Nav bar content right but you dont want to see that move motion in Nav bar". You can give a try if it helps.

Comment: What do mean by updating nav bar content? Should i not set the title and right button? Should i set them before pushing controller?

Comment: Anyway I can get your code, probably that will help us both :)

Comment: interestingly when i push the first controller (the one that shows Next button), i don't see this problem. It only happens when i push the second controller. So i guess it has nothing to do with the navigation controller.